# symfony 2.7 (tinymce && responsible file manager)

Tags: symfony2, tinymce

Для подключения RFM в качестве плагина к tinymce нужно скопировать некоторые файлы в директорию с редактором, что находится у вендорах и выполнить команду `assets:install` для того что бы получить доступ извне. Но копировать файлы вручную у вендор нельзя, так как при обновлении все упадет. Как сделать правильно?

Путь к нужной директории у вендорах, которую нужно добавлять вручную: `/vendor/stfalcon/tinymce-bundle/Stfalcon/Bundle/TinymceBundle/Resources/public/vendor/tinymce/plugins/responsivefilemanager`

Тут должна находиться скопированная директория с RFM после `assets:install`: `/web/bundles/stfalcontinymce/vendor/tinymce/plugins/responsivefilemanager`

Comment: Вы подключили bundle в AppKernel.php?

Comment: я не подключал bundle для RFM

Comment: так подключите.